# Sequelize – a way to define dynamic property

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model called `Activity`, that belongs to another model called `User`.

I want to be able to generate a dynamic property on the Activity model, so I did the following:

```
class Activity extends Sequelize.Model {
    toJSON() {
      return {
        ...this.dataValues,
        my_property: 'its value', // Dynamic property
      };
    }
}
```

This works quite fine when I query the Activity itself (or get them all), but the property is not there when I query a User with its activities e.g.

```
const user = await User.findByPk('some-pk-here', { include: [Activity] });
```

Can this behavior be changed, and if yes then how?